# Fatal error: No matching function for overloaded

Tags: php, fuelphp

Deployed application to production and running into the following error on views that contain a call to a render function:

> Fatal error: No matching function for overloaded 'render'

Example 
/fuel/app/views/profile.php:

```
echo render('_validation');
```

Render is defined in /fuel/core/classes/view.php. The Autoloader should be making this available.

Ideas on environmental issues that may be causing this?

Edit: Both APPPATH and COREPATH hold the correct file paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure if it is an issue specific with 5.3.3 but we just changed render() to View::forge() across the applications and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use more clear function names, so you won't get in trouble with standart PHP functions.
2. It looks like your render-function is declared inside a class, if it is so you have to initialize an object of that class or use an existing object to call the method

   echo $object->render('_validation');

Comment: This is part of the FuelPHP framework so that isn't an option. This works fine on a few other boxes not to mention all the FuelPHP installs out there. There is something specific with this box that may have to do with the Autoloader and with the Apache config.